# What is the correct way to compare two Pair<?,?>?

Tags: java

What is the correct way to compare two `Pair<?,?>` ?

I use this code, but I'm not 100% sure about it?
May be you know another better solution?

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Pair<?,?>) {
            Pair<?, ?> otherPair = (Pair<?, ?>) other;
            return  equalsPart(this._first, otherPair._first) &&  equalsPart(this._second, otherPair._second);
        }
        return false;
    }


public boolean equalsPart(Class<?> one, Class<?> two) {
    return ((one== two || (one!= null && two != null && one.equals(two))));
}
```

Comment: The "correct" way is whatever your requirement says it is. There is no "correct" way beyond that. What is it you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(this == other)
            return true;

        if (!(other instanceof Pair)) {
            return false;
        }


        Pair<?, ?> otherPair = (Pair<?, ?>) other;

        return Equality.equals(this.first,otherPair._first) &&
               Equality.equals(this._second, otherPair._second);
    }


    class Equality{
         public static boolean equals(Object first, Object second){ 
              return first == null ? second == null : first.equals(second);
         }
    }
```

You will find this kind of idiom being followed in many libraries for `equals()`. A precondition check and a fail fast  approach to `equals()`.

Have created a new Utility `Equality` for use in further classes which improves readability as well as provides proper `null` checking.

Comment: Thank for your reply. (Especially in the last correction. Without it, the answer would be not true).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I got the point and have edited the answer accordingly. Also for ints it was just to provide a cleaner look.

Comment: @280Z28 Gotcha. Have updated the answer to only provide relevant code.

Comment: You should perform your `this==other` check before the `other instanceof Pair` check, so the type check doesn't have to be performed unless you are actually going to use the result of it.

Comment: @280Z28 A good point indeed. Updated the asnwer. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following is an accurate solution to this. Since neither Java nor the OP provide a definition for `Pair<?, ?>`, I have included the complete definition for [the class I actually use](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4/blob/optimized/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/misc/Tuple2.java) below. The code includes a definition of `hashCode` for completeness.

```
public class Tuple2<T1, T2> {

    private final T1 item1;
    private final T2 item2;

    public Tuple2(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.item2 = item2;
    }

    public final T1 getItem1() {
        return item1;
    }

    public final T2 getItem2() {
        return item2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (!(obj instanceof Tuple2<?, ?>)) {
            return false;
        }

        Tuple2<?, ?> other = (Tuple2<?, ?>)obj;
        return Tuple.equals(this.item1, other.item1)
            && Tuple.equals(this.item2, other.item2);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 79 * hash + (this.item1 != null ? this.item1.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 79 * hash + (this.item2 != null ? this.item2.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the unusual approach.